# How to handle json response using retrofit if json field type changed dynamically

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2

I am using retrofit 2 for parsing api.
For some responses it is done successfully but for some it stops and showing error

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.NumberFormatException:
>   Invalid double: ""

Response which parses successfully is:

```
{
    "post_list": [{

        "like_count": "1",
        "like_id": 47,
        "like_user_id": 24,
        "like_full_name": "Zika zika",
        "like_full_image": "http:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/123456789\/picture?type=large",
        "comment_count": 7,
        "comment_id": 235,
        "comment_text": "Xhhc",
        "comment_user_id": 22,
        "comment_full_name": "Azz Sha",
        "comment_full_image": "http:\/\/demo.net\/apps\/demo\/web\/img\/uploads\/abc.jpg"
    }],
    "is_last": "N",
    "code": 200,
    "status": "Success"
}
```

And the one with failure is:

```
{
    "post_list": [{

        "like_count": "0",
        "like_id": "",
        "like_text": "",
        "like_user_id": "",
        "like_full_name": "",
        "like_full_image": "",
        "comment_count": 0,
        "comment_id": "",
        "comment_text": "",
        "comment_user_id": "",
        "comment_full_name": "",
        "comment_full_image": ""
    }],
    "is_last": "N",
    "code": 200,
    "status": "Success"
}
```

And PostList class:

```
     @SerializedName("like_count")
        private String likeCount;

        @SerializedName("like_id")
        private Integer likeId;

        @SerializedName("like_user_id")
        private Integer likeUserId;

        @SerializedName("like_full_name")
        private String likeText;

        @SerializedName("like_text")
        private String likeFullName;

        @SerializedName("like_full_image")
        private String likeFullImage;

        @SerializedName("comment_count")
        private Integer commentCount;

        @SerializedName("comment_id")
        private String commentId;

        @SerializedName("comment_text")
        private String commentText;

        @SerializedName("comment_user_id")
        private String commentUserId;

        @SerializedName("comment_full_name")
        private String commentFullName;

        @SerializedName("comment_full_image")
        private String commentFullImage;

//getter setters
```

I don't understand retrofit a much but I tried using this class as de-serializer, with reference of [this](http://www.javacreed.com/gson-typeadapter-example/) but still no luck.

```
public class TimelineDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<PostList> {
    @Override
    public PostList deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        PostList postList=gson.fromJson(json, PostList.class);
        final JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
        if(postList.getLikeCount().equals("0")){
            final int likeId=jsonObject.get("like_id").getAsInt();
            final int likeUserID=jsonObject.get("like_user_id").getAsInt();
            postList.setLikeId(likeId);
            postList.setLikeUserId(likeUserID);
        }

        return postList;
    }
}
```

For initializing retrofit:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();

        gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(PostList.class, new TimelineDeserializer());
                Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();

        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)).build();
```

I am getting the response body in log but then onFailure method is encountered.
Not getting how to do this. Can anything be done instead of changing that in backend? Help appreciate!

Comment: Changing type of field? There is just one solution to this: fix the Json produced by the server. That's just terrible Json.

Comment: @XaverKapeller Yes it is very bad I agree. I can do that,  just wanted to know what I can do in this situation.

Comment: i think your response is mismatched with some field try by creating Model class once again from your current Json Response

Comment: @UttamPanchasara I made the model class from [this](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) and it gives **Integer** type for fields in the correct response I have stated above and **String** type for same fields if response is kind of other one.

Comment: @Bee You can't do anything in this situation. The server might as well provide invalid json all together - for all intents and purposes it is actually invalid json since the server is breaking its own schema. It's just unuseable. Sure you may be able to workaround this somehow, but that should never be your aim. The server is the one doing something wrong here. That's the real mistake. Fix it - and then everybody will be having a much easier time.

Comment: @XaverKapeller Thanks for the guidance. I don't know much of it so wanted to make sure the problem is not because of coding.

Comment: @XaverKapeller post your last comment as an answer so that I can accept that. Because thats correct.

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting help from commentators I found that such responses **cannot be handled** with this kind of library which **uses reflection to assign values**.

Because the **server** might **provide invalid json** all together, it is actually invalid json since the server is breaking its own schema. It may be **done with a workaround** somehow, but that is not a good aim.

So, I ended up using another library for parsing this response.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you define `likeUserId` and `likeUserId` as `Integer`. However, in the JSON, `like_id` and `like_user_id` are `""` which is `String` instead of `Integer`.

Comment: Yes the are integer in some responses like in `"like_id": 47,
        "like_user_id": 2` so taken as integer. But when "like_count":  is 0 they become " ",

Comment: @Bee But you cannot assign "" to Integer just like you are writing your code. You should define an Integer for this situation. For example, you can set it to -1 instead.

Comment: Yes I know that cannot be done. that's why asked the question. Normal responses are in integer only but some of them are empty strings. And those empty string cannot be parsed as integer.

Comment: @Bee Then you cannot use this kind of library which using reflection to assign values. You should use class like `JSONObject` to parse it yourself.

Comment: Okay.. Thanks for guidance.  I have just started with retrofit and don't know 100% of it.

Comment: These libraries are good if you can ensure your JSON is always valid.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this ("").. you can also go with `likeUserId=null` and before fetching the values.. check for null value..

Comment: Any other option instead of changing the responses from backend which can be made in android codes to get that?

Comment: either make all the fields as String.. fetch them as String value.. and parse them using Integer.parseInt(String).. in that case..you can check this (string.equal(""))